# Get transaction from ethereum blockchain via Web3

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I would like to extract the information about ethereum transaction to e.g. find out whether the transaction occur on Uniswap.

As indicated [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=get_transaction#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction), I tried `get_transaction`, and all what it can return me is the error `TransactionNotFound: Transaction with hash: 'xxxxx' not found.`

I run this command, with the transaction hash from previously mentioned page, to run it (w3 is an instance of Web3 `w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'))`):

```
w3.eth.get_transaction('0x5c504ed432cb51138bcf09aa5e8a410dd4a1e204ef84bfed1be16dfba1b22060')
```

It gives me the same error.

I tried  e.g. `w3.eth.get_block(555555)`, which works.

Comment: You must get connected to a node on the ethereum blockchain to do that. You are using loopback address instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using local node? i think your code must be like this:

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"))
```